# HBase Java API won't respond

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am currently trying to use the HBase Java API. I got a problem i couldn't find any solution to.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin;

public class Test_Jo{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    System.out.println("[i] Config: " + conf);
    try {
      Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
     
      System.out.println("[+] Connection: " + conn);

      // Connect to table
      Table table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf("nmsp_test:test"));

      System.out.println("[+] Table: " + table);

      Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("row_1"));

      System.out.println("[+] Get: " + g);

      //Result result = table.get(g);

      //System.out.println("[+] Result: " + result);

      //byte [] JSON = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("JSON"), Bytes.toBytes("data"));

      //System.out.println("JSON: " + Bytes.toString(JSON));

      Admin admin = conn.getAdmin();

      System.out.println("[+] Admin: " + admin);
      Boolean bool = admin.tableExists(TableName.valueOf("nmsp_test:test"));

      System.out.println("[i] Table exists: " + bool);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Everthing will run until the programm hits the `admin.tableExists` line, then it just freezes and does nothing. The same thing occurs in the commmented out part of code when it hits the `table.get` line.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved after copying the config files from hbase and hadoop into the project directory.